# Can we create login page same as google?

Tags: google-data-api, google-signin

I am developing a google application in which I am giving a google login page to the users. so that users can login through this page.

Now, I am developing a login page same as Google. Is it allowed to do so?
Are there any legal concerns doing so ?

Any kind of resources/links are appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Vijay

Comment: Its only allowed when trying to do Man-in-the-Middle Attacks :-; I mean: Yes there are legal concerns. In fact, I'll bet you Google will suspend your account very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is most likely some legal complications in duplicating the graphical design of their login form. In a worst case (very likely) scenario, users will think they are being phished and abandon your service.

If you want people to authenticate in a very google-like fashion, try looking into google's [OAuth](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html) and OpenId services.